# R: Using hurdle() in pslc for paired data

Tags: r

I need to build a hurdle model for paired data in R.

I am running into numerous of errors trying to use glmmADMB (making the pairing a random effect).

The pscl package works beautifully, but I haven't been able to find a way to incorporate the pairing.

Is there a way to account for pairing in hurdle()?

Comment: See [here](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2017/05/01/132753) for possible alternative packages. I've just read the article this morning and haven't yet tested any of the packages. Note that the article specifically mentions that pscl can't model random effects.

Comment: Thanks very much @Marius! However, it seems like there should be a way to account for pairing without using a random effect. Perhaps by making a vector of differences between the pairs and using that as the response? Is this second question better suited for Cross Validated?

Comment: The package in the link that @Marius added above (glmmTMB) is indeed very useful for this issue. I highly recommend it.